# Is there any Audio Testing Hardware?

Tags: audio, hardware

We want to test sound characteristics of lets say an android device emitting audio out of the speaker, is there any Audio Testing Hardware which can tell in real time the heard sound pitch, frequency, loudness , etc?

I have searched for this [Audio Testing Hardware](https://www.listeninc.com/products/audio-testing-hardware/)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single steady tone, a Tuner (that musicians use to practice with to check their intonation) would give you the frequency.

The free software Audacity has some nice analysis tools, including fourier analysis.

For more advanced tools, I'd check at the [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) or [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) forums.